# Call Register Modal from Login Modal and call Login Modal from Register Modal...causing memory stack full error

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where the user can click **create account** from login modal to show registration modal [**Registration is a child of Login**].

Similarly the user can click **login** from registration modal to show login modal [**Login is a child of Registration**].

The problem is I am loading login modal in my home page.Since both modal are constantly loading each other, i am getting stack memory full error.

How should i avoid this case but have the ability to do both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (Modal version) :**

Basically, you can not have A child of B and B child of A, as it turns into an infinite loop. So, one way to solve that is to have one parent and two children.

Your parent displays one of its children at a time, and the children can notify the parent to change to the other child.

Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/VcWXeL?p=preview

```
See code in above link
```

I created one parent (AuthModal - I didn't use a modal but a div as I couldn't make the libs work on the plundr; but it works the same way) and 2 children (LoginForm and RegisterForm).

The parent keeps the state of the form displayed (attribute isLoginForm) and its template displays the component LoginForm when the attribute is true and RegisterForm when the attribute is false, using ngIf directive.

The children display their respective form (Login or Register) and a button to change to the other state (Login to Register or Register to Login). This button will emit a custom event to the parent, which will change the state of isLoginForm attribute, making it display the other child component with the other form.

As I said, this is one of the ways to do it. I could have used only one component AuthModal and write the two forms inside its template, saving 2 children components and events. But this is clearer this way.

Hope this helped!

**Old answer (non-modal only) :**

You could create a parent Component (like AuthComponent) which can load your LoginComponent and RegisterComponent.

So in the parent component you can use the router-outlet tag where you load one of your childs components at a time.

Then in each child component you use your link to give the ability to load the other one with routerLink directive.

Comment: i can not use router-outlet, because all of them are popups..you can not navigate to a popup :P

Comment: Oops. My bad! I did not notice the "modal" part!.. But having a parent component still hold, even without routing. You could handle two status (login and register) in it and show forms depending on it. I will update my answer once I have access to a computer.

Comment: in your example, how to configure which modal to show in default on click of the open modal button. In some cases i want to show login as default, but in some other case i want to show registration as default.

Comment: You can pass it as an Input argument to AuthModal component. I updated my Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/VsctSzg2sJyzSHLTcTEC?p=preview

Comment: its not working when i click register button after clicking login button

Comment: Updated again. The first time, I wrote it so that you can open it once only and then change the form using "Switch to" button.
Now that I use onChanges instead of onInit, it handles modifications of @Input-annotated field, so you can click "Open X Modal as default" as much as you want.

Comment: thanks for your effort bro..i have fixed my issue but still there is a bug in the plnkr code. Click on login modal button , inside the login modal click swtich to register, now click on the login modal button and check...sorry for troubling, just interested in learning better coding practices :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. There is a bug in my plunkr when executing exactly what you said :)
Click on "Login modal" makes : isLoginDefault=true and isLoginForm=true.
Click on "Switch to register" changes isLoginForm to false (isLoginDefault stays true).
Then on the second click on "Login modal", it changes isLoginDefault to true. As it was already true, the onChanges function is not called, that's why isLoginForm is not changed back to true.
But anyway, this should not be a problem with a modal as you should always only have one modal active, so you can't click on "Open X Modal" multiple time.

Answer (score 1):

Dont do that way it goes for infinite recursive calls.

Have a container component which acts as parent for both LoginComponent and RegistrationComponent

```
<login-component #login (registerClicked)="openRegister($event)"></login-component>
<registration-component #register></registration-component>
```

When Register button of login component is clicked emit a event and handle that in your container component and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

the below piece of code worked for me

```
@Component({
selector: 'user-management',
template: `
        <login-modal-app #loginModal (switchToRegister)="switchToRegister()"></login-modal-app>
        <register-modal-app #registerModal (switchToLogin)="switchToLogin()"></register-modal-app>
`,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class UserManagementComponent {
@ViewChild('loginModal') public loginModal: LoginModalComponent;
@ViewChild('registerModal') public registerModal: RegistrationModalComponent;

constructor() { }

switchToRegister() {
    this.loginModal.hideModal();
    this.registerModal.showModal();
}
switchToLogin() {
    this.registerModal.hideModal();
    this.loginModal.showModal();
}
}
```